# How good are snow goggles for UV protection?

Tags: vision, uv-rays, light-sensitivity, protection

Snow goggles are sometimes used to protect against [photokeratitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photokeratitis) (a.k.a. snow blindness). How good are [snow goggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_goggles) for UV protection? E.g., do they block 99 to 100 percent of both UVA and UVB rays, like [decent](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/adult-health/expert-answers/uv-protection/faq-20058021) sunglasses do? Or are they pretty much useless for UV protection?

Examples of snow goggles:

https://youtu.be/6pFWwL7tZvE?t=3m59s :

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_goggles :

[image]

[image]

[image]